# user form losing connection to a header file after running processing script

Tags: php, forms, processing

Problem:
user entry form(newproject.php) script seems to lose connection to the file header.php located in newproject.php after returning from savenewproject.php script(form processing script).

working with 2 files
1. newproject.php - user entry form (includeds header.php file which has the link to the css file)
2. savenewproject.php- form processing script

error message:

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /layout/header.php on line 2

so basically newproject.php calls savenewproject.php to process the data. if an error is found the script below returns back to the calling script(newproject.php and it displays the error messages if any. when it returns back to the calling script it losses the link to the header.php file...how can i prevent this?

//newproject.php - the calling script

```
 <?php
include('header.php'); 
if (!empty($errorString))
    {    echo '<div class="error">' . $errorString . '</div>';    }

    if (!empty($successString))
    {    $emailaddress = ''; 
        $budget = '';
        $projecttitle ='';
        $projectdescription = '';
        <div id="divfadeout" class="success">' . $successString . '</div>';
    }
?>
<form name ='newProject' action="../inc/savenewproject.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
the rest are form fields
</form>
```

// savenewproject.php - what i believed to be the problem area.

```
if(count($fieldErrors) > 0)
{    $errorString = '<p>There was an error processing the form.</p>';
    $errorString . 'ul>';
    foreach($fieldErrors as $errorVal)
    {    $errorString .= "<li>$errorVal</li>"; }
        $errorString .= '</ul>';
    include ('../layout/newproject.php');               
}
else
{
```

on line 2 is a link to a utility.inc.php file
and the folder structure is
htdocs/ 
      /inc
      /layout
      /images

Comment: What is on line 2 of `/layout/header.php`? That is where your problem lies.

Comment: could you give us a project directory tree? this should be easy to resolve if that is provided

Comment: on line 2 is a : include('inc/utilities.inc.php'); and the tree structure is htdocs/ has the following folders, layout,inc.